# How to find window(gnome-terminal) by process id which run in it?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome, gnome-terminal

gnome-terminal can open many windows, and in one window may have several tabs.

I want to active one gnome-terminal window which has a bash run in one of its tabs, for the CWD of that bash preventing my portable disk from ejecting properly.

I found the bash pid is 25938 by lsof.

In my example, I found there's 5 windows, 8 tabs. The issue is how to figure out 25938 in which window, by cmd of course.

```bsh
$ echo $$
24674
$ ps --ppid $(pgrep gnome-terminal) 
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6080 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 6742 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
20340 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
23354 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
24674 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
25938 pts/9    00:00:00 bash
30028 pts/12   00:00:00 bash
30492 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
$ wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pidof gnome-terminal-server)"
0x02800006  0 6070   bill me@bill: ~/m
0x0281016b  0 6070   bill me@bill: ~/c
0x02824e87  0 6070   bill me@bill: /c
0x02827a5d  0 6070   bill me@bill: ~/b
0x0282bc75  0 6070   bill me@bill: ~/a
```